# Context Action Menu Item not working in iOS PCL Project

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'm making an MenuItem dynamic in a PCL project, constructing this when the list view are appearing.

This is my xaml:

```
  <ListView  x:Name="ListParceiros" RowHeight="60" ItemTapped="Parceiros_Tapped" Style="{StaticResource listViewGlobalStyle}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell Appearing="OnItemAppearing">
          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="#fff">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
              <Label Text = "{Binding Nome}" FontSize="24" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.25, 0.25, 400, 40"/>
              <Label Text = "{Binding CpfCnpj}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="50, 35, 200, 25"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

And my cs file:

```
private void OnItemAppearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewCell theViewCell = (ViewCell)sender;
    var item = theViewCell.BindingContext as Pessoa;
    theViewCell.ContextActions.Clear();

    if (item != null)
    {
        var pessoaVinculo = _pessoaVinculoRepository.Get(w => w.PessoaId == item.PessoaId && w.NegocioId == App.CurrentUser.NegocioId);
        if (pessoaVinculo.NegocioAtivo)
        {
            var desativarAction = new MenuItem { Text = "Desativar", IsDestructive = true };
            desativarAction.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding("."));
            desativarAction.Clicked += DesativarParceiro;

            var servicoAction = new MenuItem { Text = "Serviços" };
            servicoAction.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding("."));
            servicoAction.Clicked += CallServicos;

            theViewCell.ContextActions.Add(desativarAction);
            theViewCell.ContextActions.Add(servicoAction);
        }
        else
        {
            var aceitarVinculoAction = new MenuItem { Text = "Aceitar Vinculo" };
            aceitarVinculoAction.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding("."));
            aceitarVinculoAction.Clicked += AceitarConvite;

            theViewCell.ContextActions.Add(aceitarVinculoAction);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to access the MenuItem in Android it's work fine, but in iOS the MenuItem are not working.
How could i make this work?

Comment: What about the menu items are not working on iOS?

Comment: When I pull left nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using two DataTemplates, one for each case, each one with the needed ContextActions, then use `DataTemplateSelector` to show the right DataTemplate.

Create your `DataTemplateSelector` and override the `OnSelectTemplate` method returning the right DataTemplate depending on your condition (`pessoaVinculo.NegocioAtivo` in your case).

Know more about DataTemplateSelector in
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/data-templates/selector